# Large images prevent div from fading in

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I've got this setup:

```
<div id="container1">
    <!-- content from one section -->
</div>
<div id="container2" style="display:none;">
    <div id="sub-container">
        <img src="image1.png" />
        <img src="image2.png" />
        <!-- 20 or so images sit here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

`container1` is initially displayed. On document.ready, all but the first four images are hidden away in order to build a carousel of sorts.
The user clicks a button, `container1` fades out and `container2` fades in.

The first time the user clicks the button, `container2` doesn't fade in, instead it jumps straight to visible. The second time, fade in works as normal.

The images involved are pretty substantial (~10MB total size) but that hasn't been an issue so far as the page is meant to be viewed locally. The fact that the issue doesn't appear if I've got one or two images tells me the browser is struggling to both load the images and fade in at the same time. The second time it loads, the images have been cached and fade in as normal.

I tried a form of preloading like so:

```
/* take the div outside the viewport but still render it */
.hide {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
}

var cacheContainer = "<div class='hide'></div>",
    $images = $("#sub-container img");
// move the images to the container
$(cacheContainer).appendTo("body").append($images);

// hopefully 500ms would be enough for the images to render?
setTimeout(function () {
    images.appendTo("#sub-container");
    doGallery(); // build carousel
},500);
```

... this however leads to the same issue - `container2` pops in instead of fading the first time round, and works perfectly fine afterwards.

Any ideas?

---

As requested, here's what I use to hide/show the containers:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $currentTab = $("#container1"),
        $newTab,
        newTabName;

    // a couple of more unrelated setting up functions go here

    doImageCaching(); // the function I've got above

    $("#container2").hide();

    $("#tab-links>a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // probably a bit cheeky doing it this way but oh well
        newTabName = $(this).attr("id").replace("-btn", "");
        if($currentTab.attr("id") === newTabName) {
            return;
        }
        $newTab = $("#" + newTabName);

        $newTab.stop(true, true).fadeToggle(200);
        $currentTab.stop(true, true).delay(100).fadeToggle(200);
        $currentTab = $newTab;
        $newTab = null;
    });
});
```

Here's `#tab-links` for reference:

```
<div id="tab-links">
    <a id="container1-btn" href="#">show container 1</a>
    <a id="container2-btn" href="#">show container 2</a>
</div>
```

---

**Edit 2** So I just noticed something new: so the second time I switch to `container2` it fades in as normal. If I wait 10 seconds or so, and then try and switch to `container2` *again*, the problem reappears.

So it seems to me loading the DOM has nothing to do with this, and I'm dealing with Chrome's internal memory. So it loads the images, and then "forgets" about them when they hide again. Yikes.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how to keep the browser from "forgetting" the images, or is that a direction I shouldn't really take?

Comment: What does `doGallery` do? Does it work with smaller images?

Comment: `doGallery` does a number of things, including iterating through each of the large images, changing their position, hiding all but the first four, adding some event listeners, etc. This is all done before the user clicks the button that fades in `container2`.

Comment: I'm not really sure if it's worth mentioning but I'll do it anyway - the images are all shrunk down to about a third of their visible size (using `height` and `width` in the markup) and only expand when they're clicked later on.

Comment: Yes, show us the code that fades in the images.

Comment: Updated my question, see above.

Comment: The image DOM contains an onLoad [event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_img_onload.asp) that it is easily accessible by jquery which you might use to make sure that the images are really loaded completely. I suggest that you try to change the function in the timeout and use that function in the onLoad event instead and see what happens.

Comment: No dice... I've tried moving both doGallery() and doImageCaching() in a $(window).load, to no effect. Anyway, I just noticed something new about the issue - I think DOM loading has nothing to do with it. See above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up converting my ultra-high quality PNGs to ultra-high quality JPGs - this led to an approximately 20-30% reduction in file size with barely any reduction in apparent quality. My problem disappeared, too.

The moral of the story is: even if you're developing a page that isn't going online, you still need to optimize your images.

Thank you all for your help.